# Sending email using constant contact mail server instead of php mail

Tags: php, email, constantcontact

From past few days, I am searching for a solution in Constant Contact APIs at http://developer.constantcontact.com/libraries/sample-code.html,, but was unable to find it. So, below is our requirement.

In my website we have donations, memberships etc. When a user fills Donation form or Membership form or Contact form etc., once user submits the form, we need to send a confirmation email to user.Our requirement is, we want this email to be send from Constant Contact mail server instead of send grid or php mail server. we have already account in constant contact for sending news letters. we need to use those details foe sending confirmation emails for single user and store the email ID in our Constant Contact Account.

We need the helpful APIs to communicate in the above procedure/manner.

We didn't find any solution to send email for single donated user. how to send email to single user and message.

Current we are using third party service(Send Grid), now we would like to move to Constant Contact. We have developed this website in PHP programming language.

Kindly help us to integrate in the above procedure/manner.

Here i attached the file. i am getting error when i using the given API's and format

Below is my simple code

```
     <?php

require_once 'Ctct/autoload.php';

use Ctct\ConstantContact;
use Ctct\Components\Contacts\Contact;
use Ctct\Components\Contacts\ContactList;
use Ctct\Components\Contacts\EmailAddress;
use Ctct\Components\EmailMarketing\Campaign;
use Ctct\Components\EmailMarketing\MessageFooter;
use Ctct\Components\EmailMarketing\Schedule;
use Ctct\Exceptions\CtctException;

// Enter your Constant Contact APIKEY and ACCESS_TOKEN
define("APIKEY", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
define("ACCESS_TOKEN", "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-989939366970");

$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$cc = new ConstantContact(APIKEY);

try {
    $lists = $cc->getLists(ACCESS_TOKEN);
} catch (CtctException $ex) {
    foreach ($ex->getErrors() as $error) {
        print_r($error);
    }
}
print_r($lists);

if (isset($_POST['email']) && strlen($_POST['email']) > 1) {
    $action = "Getting Contact By Email Address";
    try {
        // check to see if a contact with the email addess already exists in the account
        $response = $cc->getContactByEmail(ACCESS_TOKEN, $_POST['email']);
        // create a new contact if one does not exist
        if (empty($response->results)) {
            $action = "Creating Contact";
            $contact = new Contact();
            $contact->addEmail($_POST['email']);
            $contact->addList($_POST['list']);
            $contact->first_name = $_POST['fname'];
            $contact->last_name = $_POST['fname'];
            /*
             * The third parameter of addContact defaults to false, but if this were set to true it would tell Constant
             * Contact that this action is being performed by the contact themselves, and gives the ability to
             * opt contacts back in and trigger Welcome/Change-of-interest emails.
             *
             * See: http://developer.constantcontact.com/docs/contacts-api/contacts-index.html#opt_in
             */
            $returnContact = $cc->addContact(ACCESS_TOKEN, $contact, true);
            // update the existing contact if address already existed
        } else {
            $action = "Updating Contact";
            $contact = $response->results[0];
            $contact->addList($_POST['list']);
            $contact->first_name = $_POST['fname'];
            $contact->last_name = $_POST['fname'];
            /*
             * The third parameter of updateContact defaults to false, but if this were set to true it would tell
             * Constant Contact that this action is being performed by the contact themselves, and gives the ability to
             * opt contacts back in and trigger Welcome/Change-of-interest emails.
             *
             * See: http://developer.constantcontact.com/docs/contacts-api/contacts-index.html#opt_in
             */
            $returnContact = $cc->updateContact(ACCESS_TOKEN, $contact, true);
        }

    }
        catch (CtctException $ex) {
        echo '<span class="label label-important">Error ' . $action . '</span>';
        echo '<div class="container alert-error"><pre class="failure-pre">';
        print_r($ex->getErrors());
        echo '</pre></div>';
        die();
    }
}



function createCampaign(array $params)
{
    $cc = new ConstantContact(APIKEY);
    $campaign = new Campaign();
    $campaign->name = $params['fname'];
    $campaign->subject = "Test Mail Subject";
    $campaign->from_name = $params['fname'];
    $campaign->from_email = $params['email'];
    //$campaign->greeting_string = $params['greeting_string'];
    //$campaign->reply_to_email = $params['email'];
    $campaign->text_content = $params['content_text'];
    $campaign->email_content = $params['content_text'];
    $campaign->email_content_format = 'HTML';
    // add the selected list or lists to the campaign
$campaign->addList('venky.para@gmail.com');
    return $cc->addEmailCampaign(ACCESS_TOKEN, $campaign);
}

function createSchedule($campaignId, $time)
{
    $cc = new ConstantContact(APIKEY);
    $schedule = new Schedule();
    $schedule->scheduled_date = $time;
    return $cc->addEmailCampaignSchedule(ACCESS_TOKEN, $campaignId, $schedule);
}

global $wpdb;
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$fname=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
$useremail=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$content=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['content_text']);


    // attempt to create a campaign with the fields submitted, displaying any errors that occur
    try {
        $campaign = createCampaign($_POST);
    } catch (CtctException $ex) {
        echo '<span class="label label-important">Error Creating Campaign</span>';
        echo '<div class="container alert-error"><pre class="failure-pre">';
        print_r($ex->getErrors());
        echo '</pre></div>';
        die();
    }

    // attempt to schedule a campaign with the fields submitted, displaying any errors that occur
    try {
        $schedule = createSchedule($campaign->id,$date);
    } catch (CtctException $ex) {
        echo '<span class="label label-important">Error Scheduling Campaign</span>';
        echo '<div class="container alert-error"><pre class="failure-pre">';
        print_r($ex->getErrors());
        echo '</pre></div>';
        die();
    }


}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validtestmail(){
var fname=document.getElementById('fname').value;
var email=document.getElementById('email').value;
var content_text=document.getElementById('content_text').value;
if(fname=='')
  {
  alert('Enter Name');
  document.getElementById('fname').focus();
  return false;
  }
  else if(email=='')
  {
  alert('Enter Email');
  document.getElementById('email').focus();
  return false;
  }
  else if(content_text=='')
  {
  alert('Enter Content');
  document.getElementById('content_text').focus();
  return false;
  }


}
</script>
<div class="container ">
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <div class="innerPagesBlock fullWidth">



                 <div id="primary" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 content-area contactbg">
<div class="myprofileHeading">Change Password </div>
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="member_cp" name="member_cp" action="<?php echo get_bloginfo('home'); ?>/testmail" method="post" onsubmit="return validtestmail();" style="margin-top:30px;">
            <!-- Self form start-->   

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 formLog">
            <span style="font-size:16px; font-weight: bold; color: #FFFFFF;">
                <?php  
                if($msg)
                {?>
                    <div class="<?php echo $class; ?>" role="alert"><?php
                        echo $msg;
                        ?>
                    </div><?php
                } 
                ?>
                </span>
            </div>  


      <div class="form-login formMain">

        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label">Name:<span>*</span></label>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 formLog">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname"  placeholder="Name" value="" >
        </div>
         <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label">Email: <span>*</span></label>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 formLog">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="" >
        </div>
         <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label">Content: <span>*</span></label>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 formLog">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="content_text" name="content_text" placeholder="Content" value="" >
        </div>

         <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 formLog">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btnSubmit" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 formLog">
     <button type="reset" name="button2" id="button2" class="btn btn-primary btnReset">Reset</button>
    </div>



        </div>
        </form>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="main-content" class="main-content">

<?php
    if ( is_front_page() && twentyfourteen_has_featured_posts() ) {
        // Include the featured content template.
        get_template_part( 'featured-content' );
    }
?>

</div><!-- #main-content -->
```

Here how to send email to single user. How?. Is it possible?. Please help me. My time wasting from last 2 weeks.

Thanking You

Comment: **i am getting error when i using the given api' s and format** - What error?

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [error_key] => json.type.invalid
            [error_message] => #/lists/0/id: Value is of a disallowed type. Allowed types are: String.
        )

)

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast $_POST['list'] as a string.  It may be posting as an integer.

Changing this:

```
$contact->addList($_POST['list']);
```

to this:

```
$contact->addList( (string)$_POST['list'] );
```

would probably do it.